# How to find the position of a particular number inside an array?

Tags: java

If I entered 98 means it will show the position 6.

```
public class OddEven {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 14, 23, 67, 10, 76, 5, 98, 13, 110 };
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if(numbers[i]==14)
                System.out.println(numbers[i]+"position 0");
            else 
                System.out.println(numbers[i]+"no. not in the list");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove javascript tag.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: just return i and you will have the position

Answer (score 0):

First, it is good to have something like this as a separate function for testability etc purposes.  This also makes the code clearer.  Secondly, if you are looping through, you probably don't want to do the `system.out.println` inside the loop

So you want something like:

```
public class IndexLookup {
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 14, 23, 67, 10, 76, 5, 98, 13, 110 };
    public int indexOf(int query) {
        for (int I = 0; I < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[I] == query){
                return I;
            }
        }
        return -1
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (indexOf(98) == -1) {
            System.out.println("Not in list");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Found %d at position %d%n", 98, indexOf(98));
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much....i got the answer....

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code as below it will print the expected results, if you don't want array to consider the 0 position you can always increment i value to i+1 in out put statement inside the 'if' condition present in 'for' loop :-)

```
            boolean found = false;
            int[] numbers = { 14, 23, 67, 10, 76, 5, 98, 13, 110 };
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  

            System.out.println("Enter the number to search");  
            int num =sc.nextInt();  
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if(numbers[i]==num){
                    System.out.println(numbers[i]+" position "+i);
                    found =true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found){
                System.out.println("Unable to find the Entered Number in the array");
            }
```